# IBM Cloud Speech to Text Websocket gives hexcode

Tags: python, websocket, ibm-watson

I am writing code which recognizes speech and converts it into text using **IBM Watson**. I referred [git link](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/microphone-speech-to-text.py) provided by IBM. It works fine at the end, but it gives some hex-decimal digits in the middle which I can't understand.

Is there a way to disable the intermediate hex-decimal digits that get generated by `ibm_watson.websocket` ?
Hexa-decimal digits example:

```
++Sent raw: b'\x82\xfe\x08\x00\xd3\xdf\xea\xcd\xd0\xdf\xec\xcd\xd5\xdf\xec\xcd\xd6\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd2\xdf\xea\xcd\xd2\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd0\xdf\xee\xcd\xd0\xdf\xea\xcd\xd3\xdf\xea\xcd\xd2\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd0\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd2\xdf\x152, \x172- \xea\xcd\xd1\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd1\xdf\xeb\xcd- \x172/ \x172. \x172- \x142\xd3\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd2\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd2\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd3\xdf\xea\xcd- \x172. \x152, \xea\xcd\xd2\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd1\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd0\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd1\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd2\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd1\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd2\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd2\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd2\xdf\xea\xcd\xd2\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd2\xdf\xeb\xcd\xd1\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd1\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd1\xdf\xee\xcd\xd7\xdf\xee\xcd\xd7\xdf\xef\xcd\xd6\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd7\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd0\xdf\xe9\xcd\xd1\xdf\xe8\xcd\xd2\xdf'...
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=2 data=b'\x03\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x05\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfd\xff\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff\xfd\xff\xfc\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfe\xff\xfe\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfe\xff\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00'....
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is only DEBUG output, try `logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)` to disable all non-critical debugging output. Remember to import logging first and write this line at the beginning of the code.